# Custom post type causes php-error in php version 5.2.17

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I'm getting an php-error on an server that runs php version 5.2.17 which doesn't support anonymous functions. I've never heard of that before (really new to php) but found out that only php 5.3.x supports the following code:

```
 add_action('init', function() use($name, $args) {
```

Is there any way to solve that problem? It works fine on version 5.3.10 but I jhave to use an old host not using php 5.3...

This is the full code to create the custom posts:

```
/* Add Post Type */
function add_post_type($name, $args = array() ) {   
    if ( !isset($name) ) return;

    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $name));

    add_action('init', function() use($name, $args) {   
        $args = array_merge(
            array(
                'label' => 'Members ' . ucwords($name) . '',
                'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $name"),
                'singular_name' => $name,
                'public' => true,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
            ),
            $args
        );

        register_post_type( $name, $args);
    });
}


add_post_type('Netherlands', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments')
));
```

Comment: are you basing it on this: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/custom-post-type-helper-class/ ?

Comment: No, the code doesn't come from that article. Found it on the Wordpress forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewrite your code without closures. It could look like this:

```
function wpse54191_plugin_init() {
    add_post_type('Netherlands', array(
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments')
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'wpse54191_plugin_init');

/* Add Post Type */
function add_post_type($name, $args = array() ) {   
    if ( !isset($name) ) return;

    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $name));
    $args = array_merge(
        array(
            'label' => 'Members ' . ucwords($name) . '',
            'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $name"),
            'singular_name' => $name,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
        ),
        $args
    );

    register_post_type( $name, $args);
}
```

Comment: +1 Anonymous functions inside action hooks is generally frowned upon. Great rewrite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that resolved the PHP-error! I'm only having some problems displaying the custom posts now but I'll look into that.